# How to Create Array Formula for image in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to create array formula to show image in spreadsheet, I used formula  it doesn't work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&I2:I))
```

The formula didn't work. How can I create an array formula to get image in row K2,K3....
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula that you have should be working fine. I tried the same with a sample images. See below screenshot.

You just need to make sure that all the images in your "ID FOTO" column are public. If they are not shared publicly, it will not be visible.

[image: Image Array formula]

Comment: I forgot to share publicly. thank @Gangula